# Method that returns either SqlConnection or MySqlConnection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to create a method that based on the provider that I'm passing either MySql or MSSQL I would like to return a SqlConnection or a MySqlConnection.

Basically something like this:

```
public Connection GetConnection(provider) {

   switch (provider) {
      case MSSQL:
         return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      case MySql:
          return new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
      default:
          return null;
}
```

Since they are different types I thought about creating an abstract class, something like.

```
public abstract class BaseSqlConnection
{
    public abstract void Open();
}

public class MSSQLServerConnection : BaseSqlConnection
{
    public MSSQLServerConnection(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }

    public SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }

    public override void Open()
    {
        Connection.Open();
    }
}
```

Problem is this is not enough, because I would also need to implement methods like CreateCommand() and others that I might need, so I would like to ask if there is any of you with an easier solution.

Comment: You need to specific every method in the abstract class and implement it into the DBMS class, what you can reuse is just the query itself if works on both server

Comment: Don't they both inherit from `System.Data.Common.DbConnection`?

Comment: @DavidG yes, so I could just return a DbConnection maybe

Comment: Or the base interface https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbconnection?view=net-5.0 however if I am not wrong MySql has some specific properties that would not be available in this way

Comment: DbProviderFactory provides these in-built. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both objects inherit from the same base class, [`DbConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?view=net-5.0), you can do this:

```
public DbConnection GetConnection(provider) {

   switch (provider) {
      case MSSQL:
         return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      case MySql:
          return new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
      default:
          return null;
}
```

Note you may need to add `using System.Data.Common;`

Edit:

To incorporate Jon's suggestion, it would look like this:

```
public DbConnection GetConnection(string provider) => 
    provider switch
    {
        MSSQL => new SqlConnection(connectionString),
        MySql => new MySqlConnection(connectionString),
        _ => throw new ArgumentException("Unknown provider", nameof(provider))
    };
```

Comment: Note that with C# 8 switch expressions, this can be even simpler. I'd personally suggest throwing an `ArgumentException` for an unknown provider rather than returning null though.

Comment: yeap it works, I've also added the argumentexception which makes sense too

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, added your suggestions in too.

Comment: I'd suggest turning this question & answer into a more generic use case: "How to return two different types?" (or something) and first asking "do they share a common ancestor or interface?" and use this usecase as an exemple (I didn't find it doing a quick search) so it can be used as a duplicate for later questions.

Comment: @DavidG: I should have been clearer - it being a switch expression *also* means you can implement the method as an expression-bodied member, which makes the whole thing much more streamlined than the statement version.

Comment: @JonSkeet Gotcha, and agreed  - happy to remove curly braces where possible!